# PowerShell group and sort in the same table

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have a list of objects in PowerShell:

```
Date                Name       Type
----                ----       ----
12/20/2019 00:00:00 HUiigfiesh Foo
5/3/2018 00:00:00   IOUifue    Bar
11/19/2018 00:00:00 KFEH       Baz
6/9/2020 00:00:00   ohiHOI     Bar
3/1/2017 00:00:00   iifehiu    Foo
5/12/2020 00:00:00  skjUIH     Baz
1/9/2016 00:00:00   hH         Baz
6/4/2012 00:00:00   oOIJofiej  Foo
12/31/2019 00:00:00 oiJOEIJ    Bar
9/15/2020 00:00:00  oiOIJWFOij Baz
8/11/2018 00:00:00  KHoijoj    Foo
```

How can I group them by one property, and then within those groups, sort them by another property, and get the output back in one table? For example, if I wanted to group by Type and then sort those groups by Date, I would want to get the output back like this:

```
Date                Name       Type
----                ----       ----
6/9/2020 00:00:00   ohiHOI     Bar
12/31/2019 00:00:00 oiJOEIJ    Bar
5/3/2018 00:00:00   IOUifue    Bar
9/15/2020 00:00:00  oiOIJWFOij Baz
5/12/2020 00:00:00  skjUIH     Baz
11/19/2018 00:00:00 KFEH       Baz
1/9/2016 00:00:00   hH         Baz
12/20/2019 00:00:00 HUiigfiesh Foo
8/11/2018 00:00:00  KHoijoj    Foo
3/1/2017 00:00:00   iifehiu    Foo
6/4/2012 00:00:00   oOIJofiej  Foo
```

How can I accomplish this? I've looked into `Group-Object` and `Format-Table -GroupBy`, but they return the groups as independent tables or lists. I want the output to be in one properly sorted and grouped table or list.

Comment: the `Sort-Object` & `Group-Object` cmdlets both accept an _array_ in the `-Property` parameter. using that with `S-O will give you the collection back sorted by the property values in the order listed. if you use calculated values, you can specify the sort direction for each property ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is necessarily to `Group-Object`:

Assuming that the **Date** property is of a `DateTime` type and that the order of the grouped **Type** property isn't important:

```
$Data | Sort-Object Type,Date -Descending
```

If the (ascending) order of the grouped **Type** property is important:

```
$Data | Sort-Object Type,@{Expression = 'Date'; Descending = $True}
```

And if the **Date** property is not a `DateTime` type but actually a string:

```
$Data | Sort-Object Type,@{Expression = {[DateTime]$_.Date}; Descending = $True}
```

Answer (score 2):

I dug a bit more myself and found that you can pull the grouped objects back out of `Group-Object`'s output, and then sort those groups before outputting them again. The code that get's exactly what I'm looking for is:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $data | Group-Object -Property Type | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object -Property Date -Descending}

Date                Name       Type
----                ----       ----
6/9/2020 00:00:00   ohiHOI     Bar
12/31/2019 00:00:00 oiJOEIJ    Bar
5/3/2018 00:00:00   IOUifue    Bar
9/15/2020 00:00:00  oiOIJWFOij Baz
5/12/2020 00:00:00  skjUIH     Baz
11/19/2018 00:00:00 KFEH       Baz
1/9/2016 00:00:00   hH         Baz
12/20/2019 00:00:00 HUiigfiesh Foo
8/11/2018 00:00:00  KHoijoj    Foo
3/1/2017 00:00:00   iifehiu    Foo
6/4/2012 00:00:00   oOIJofiej  Foo
```

Or more simply: `$data | Group Type | Sort Name | % {$_.Group | Sort Date -Desc}`